# Git rebase and git merge

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I understand that if I have a branch ready to merge with remote master, I need to do:

1. git checkout 'my branch'
2. git rebase master (rebase because I want simple history + my changes are minuscule enough to do that). But it will be rebase with my local master, not with origin master, correct?
3. git checkout master
4. git merge 'my branch' - this will do fast-forward merge and completes the process.

But how to do the same merge with remote master? I don't see any explicit explanation in the Internet. I cannot just checkout on origin master on the 3d step.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remote master is whatever the remote repo identifies as `master`.  Whenever you fetch from the `origin` remote, git tags that remote's `master` commit as your `origin/master` (in your `remotes` refs).

The way to update a remote repo's refs is to push to it (which also sends any commits or whatever else is needed).  So:

```
git checkout master       # or however you want to get `master` current with origin
git pull                  # ...
git checkout mybranch
git rebase master
git checkout -B master    # you know it's going to --ff, so just move the ref
                          # or, you could `git checkout master; git merge mybranch`
git push origin master    # push the new commits to the remote's `master`
```

Comment: So, whatever I do, I need 'git push origin master' to apply everything to remote repository, correct? Are there any conflicts possible?

Comment: That's pretty much it.  (edit: "pretty much" is me being excruciatingly correct; you could also, in the remote repo, fetch from yours -- if the remote is actually a coworker's that's not as unusual as you might think.  any hierarchy among repositories is _entirely_ conventional.)

Comment: And no, unless someone else has pushed to the remote's master in the meantime, no conflict is possible.

Comment: Thank you. Don't think that I don't upvote you because I am rude. I just didn't earn enough reputation and cannot vote at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply rebase on top of the origin master like this

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Also you can skip 3. and 4. simple pushing your rebased branch to the origin/master

```
git push origin my_branch:master
```

Comment: Should I do ff merge after git rebase origin/master like in step 4? If yes, then how exactly?

Comment: your second suggestion doesn't comply with the requirements of remote repository's owner, so I need to do through rebase

Comment: I can't imagine, repository owner can control your local branch naming. By doing `git rebase origin/master` you ensure fast-forward merge on the server side. Pushing your `my_branch` directly to the `origin/master` perfectly fine and will still produce linear history.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Basically, the final history will look the same without any signs how it was done. Thank you for your help.